# Java-Real time push updates for web

Tags: java, spring-mvc, long-polling, real-time-java

Does Spring framework have any method to efficiently push data to web client with out cluttering the server? Long-polling is the preferred method.

Comment: Use things like WebSockets, SSE (as opposed to long-polling which uses HTTP as usual).

Comment: @Tiny my consideration is server side implementation not the client side. Its ok to use sse or websockets.

Comment: A reference implementation of JSR-356 (Tyrus) is the WebSockets implementation available in Java EE 7. (Not sure about Spring).